# How to revise the plt.subplot code to single image? ( In Github GAN code)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm using the code from github https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py

[The demo code show 25 generated image in one single image file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXIKu.png)

But I want to print every image in original size as a png file. I have tried several ways like

```
plt.imshow()
```

or

```
cv2.imwrite()
```

However, they didn't work. I can't print the correct image without subplot image.

This is the part of printing image:

```
def sample_images(self, epoch):
    r, c = 5, 5
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (r * c, self.latent_dim))
    gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

    # Rescale images 0 - 1
    gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
    cnt = 0

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            axs[i,j].imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray')
            axs[i,j].axis('off')
            cnt += 1
    fig.savefig("images/%d.png" % epoch)
    plt.close()
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a figure with 25 subplots using

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5)
```

Replace this with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` to create a figure with 1 set of axes. This also needs to go inside the loop if you want each of the 25 images to be in it's own figure. In addition, you need to move the call to `savefig` into the loop too:

```
def sample_images(self, epoch):
    r, c = 5, 5
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (r * c, self.latent_dim))
    gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

    # Rescale images 0 - 1
    gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5

    cnt = 0

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray')
            ax.axis('off')
            cnt += 1
            fig.savefig("images/%d.png" % epoch)
            plt.close()
```